# SSIS:Boolean Conversion, only getting NULL Values

Tags: ssis, boolean, type-conversion

i have a Column which i am Converting the following way:

[image: Column to be converted]

as you can see, i am taking a column (that was of the type nvarchar(255) before)
and turning it into a Bool, since all of the Values are eather "Ja" or "Nein" (German for "Yes" and "No")

The Package runs completely flawless, and i even started cheering thinking i had found the solution.
But in the Table I am only getting NULL Values? 
[image: NULL Values]

How is this explanable ?
does anybody know what i am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance
(NOTE: The Values i am using come from a SharePoint List Source that after the conversion Process are inserted into an OLE DB).

Comment: 1) What are the values in the ColumnFromNVARCHARToBOOL column right after the conversion? (Please check it with a Data Viewer)

Comment: 2) What is the destination column type in DB?

Comment: - 2) The Destination Column type in DB is "bit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code:

```
Column == "Ja" && !isnull(Column) ? TRUE : FALSE
```

Comment: Tried it, still only getting NULL Values

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just found the fix to my Problem,

wrongly assigned the Columns on the DB Destination!

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add one "Derived Column", the expression as:
!ISNULL([Your Column]) ? ([Your Column] == "Y" ?  TRUE  :  FALSE ) : NULL(DT_BOOL)

This way can also return null value if the cell is null.

Comment: Hi, Regarding your expression from the above. My  OLE DB data source has not that column that I could use to set the Boolean logic. Only the destination column has the Boolean column. Should I simply assign [0] value in the expression. If so, what is the syntax? Ir just type 0.